# cross browser hide mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to enhance a depth effect by hiding the mouse cursor as it passes over a div, is there a method that will work across all browsers?

Comment: I have to say I hate it with such passion when my cursor disapears. I would advise against such scheme.

Comment: haha yes I know exactly what you mean, but this more just for an experiment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like:

```
/* css */
div {
    cursor: url(url/to/transparent.gif), auto;
}
```

should do the trick or:

```
divEl.style.cursor = 'url(path/to/transparent.gif), auto'; // javascript
```

But hiding the cursor can annoy visitors immensly.

Addendum: In the examples I wrote .gif files, but you might actually need to convert to .cur or .ani files for better browser support.

Comment: Does this work in Opera?  (Don't have it handy, or I'd try it myself.)

Comment: dont have opera handy either, works in FF, but not in chrome it seems. Yes it would be very annoying to hide it - I'm planning on redrawing it on a canvas but simulate it underneath things

Comment: see w3cschools link provided in awnser: Note: Opera 9.3 and Safari 3 do not support URL values.

Answer (score 4):

Finding something that works across browsers is a pain.

The code below works on Chrome, IE, and Firefox. 
IE likes .cur files, Chrome likes the embedded png, and some browsers actually respect the none :)

```
#div {
    cursor: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAFBhaW50Lk5FVCB2My41LjbQg61aAAAADUlEQVQYV2P4//8/IwAI/QL/+TZZdwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='),
    url(images/blank.cur),
    none !important;
}
```

Comment: this is actually the best response here. +1

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply reduce the size of the cursor as it gets closer to the center of the deep field?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the type of cursor you use (pointer, help, crosshair,...) but to hide it... Even if this would be possible in modern browers, older browsers won't support this. Also I can't imagine why you would hide the cursor.

EDIT: in firefox when adding `cursor:none;` to the body element it hides the cursor untill I go over a link, it's maybe a start.

Comment: mmm yeah I know of changing it to the different set states, but ideally i need nothing! Im working on a canvas mega graphic demo, and ideally need the mouse to disappear so I can the simulate it say passing underneath glass

Comment: so actually it wouldn't need to be supported on older browsers thinking about it

Answer (score 0):

Using a full transparent picture will not help. (It won't let you do that`:(`)
You should use a `1x1` 1% transparent image instead, plus `cursor:none`.